# Circuit failed to establish

Tags: circuit, stem

I'm trying to build my own circuits using stem:

These are three different error messages I get from time to time:

1. Circuit failed to be created: DESTROYED
2. Circuit failed to be created: TIMEOUT
3. Unable to reach  ((7, 'Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.'))

Can someone explain what do these three error messages mean? (Plus when I try to built that same circuit again I get the error sometimes and sometimes it builds up?) Is there congestion on the network? / Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n1167

```
10 -- TIMEOUT         (Circuit construction took too long)
...
11 -- DESTROYED       (The circuit was destroyed w/o client TRUNCATE)
```

My guess is that there's something wrong with how you're trying to build the circuits in the first place. Have a look at how [ExitMap currently builds custom circuits](https://github.com/NullHypothesis/exitmap/blob/52ac9c18fd1f1627076e41f143ca0455fd6be9ec/src/exitmap.py#L407-L439).